# Puppet parameter lookup

Tags: puppet

I would like to know if it is possible to lookup the value of another Puppet resource, something like the following example:

```
define foo( $username ) {
    $home = User[$username].home
    ....
}
```

The above syntax does not work, but that is probably because I don't know Ruby well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible. Originally, Puppet used dynamic scoping for variables, but it was deprecated as of 2.7.0. See more information [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/scope_and_puppet.html) about what you should do instead.

In this particular case, however, I don't think plain scoping will do. In fact, I think you should use either [virtual resources](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/virtual_resources.html) or [exported resources](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/exported_resources.html). They are both very similar, actually, except that exported resources work inter-hosts.

Either way, you'll just have to structure your code in a very different way than what you want to do, it seems to me. Spend some time looking at complex puppet modules and understand how they go about doing what they do.

Answer (score 0):

Puppet have its own language, it doesn't use Ruby. You can define a resource as belows:

```
define add_user ( $uid ) {
    $username = $title
    user { $username:
        home    => "/home/$username",
        shell   => "/bin/bash",
        uid     => $uid
    }
}
```

and call it with:

```
add_user { tom:
    uid      => 501
}
```

[Read more](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/)...

Comment: I know, but I would like to be able to have some function call in another definition which, in your example, returns "/home/tom".

Comment: Could you please explain a little more about your situation?