# accessing a variable within a previously declared instance of a defined type

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to define a static media server that uses a common website layout (e.g. with directories `etc/`, `log/`, `html/`, etc.), as well as an nginx config that will get included into a host-wide nginx config.  The site's nginx config needs to make use of the doc root that gets defined by the declared `layouts::website` resource.

So, what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
class sites::static ($sites_dir) {

    $domain = "static.example.com"

    layouts::website {$domain:
        base_dir => $sites_dir,
        name => $domain,
    }

    nginx::siteconfig {$domain:
        domain => $domain,
        doc_root => $layouts::website[$domain]::doc_root,
    }
}
```

Which could then be used by declaring:

```
class {'sites::static': sites_dir => "/opt/sites"}
```

However, the above fails because the `$layouts::website[$domain]::doc_root` part is invalid.  I've tried various alternatives here, unsuccessfully.

Is this possible?  If not, how would you suggest I accomplish the stated goal of using a base layout that then needs to be used by various bits that will populate content within that base layout?

Comment: In essence you're trying to access a value of a parameter passed in to resource, right?  Me too.

Comment: I found this which seems to answer your question.  http://serverfault.com/questions/306446/puppet-parameter-lookup

Comment: @mogsie Not necessarily a parameter passed into a resource, but a variable that has been defined by the other resource whether passed to it or defined within it.  From what I can tell so far, it is possible to access a variable within a declared class, but not within a declared resource type.  It seems that the only way to accomplish this is to declare a variable in the `sites::static` scope and pass it to the declared resources, however doing that pretty much defeats the purpose of modularizing things into separate components in the first place.

Comment: I've also come to the same conclusion that it isn't possible to access the parameters of a given resource type :/

Comment: if that's the case, how am I supposed to use templates that get their values from parameters passed to the defined resource?

Comment: If you use a define then this define should render the template. Then the template can leverage scope inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't get at variables inside defined resources.

I would approach this by reordering the resource type definitions and putting the `nginx::siteconfig` clause inside the `layouts::website` definition.  (If every use of `layouts::website` should also have a `nginx::siteconfig` too, then nesting the one in the other is a good way to DRY.)  If you need to have some cases where a use of `layouts::website` does not also have a nginx definition, you'll have to add a parameter to `layouts::website`, something like `$nginx = true`.

Also, the following bits of code:

```
layouts::website {$domain:
    name => $domain,
}

nginx::siteconfig {$domain:
    domain => $domain,
}
```

smell like unnecessary repetition to me.  The website name and nginx domain seem like perfect candidates to be namevars so you can leave off the parameter in most cases.